# Packing items from the two ends of a row into several trucks

Tags: algorithm, packing, bin-packing

There are items in a row which have to be placed into several trucks. The weight of the items and the number of trucks and their common capacity are given. Items can be moved to the trucks only from the two ends of the row. How can we determine the maximum number of items that can be placed into the trucks?
(There can be 10000 items and 100 trucks at most.)

**Example:**
Items: (20, 70, 10, 30, 80, 60, 50, 30)
Number of trucks: 3
Capacity of trucks: 100

Here we can place max 7 items, e.g. like this:

```
item    to truck  remaining
 20     1         (70, 10, 30, 80, 60, 50, 30)
 30     2         (70, 10, 30, 80, 60, 50)
 70     2         (10, 30, 80, 60, 50)
 50     1         (10, 30, 80, 60)
 10     3         (30, 80, 60)
 30     1         (80, 60)
 60     3         (80)
```

My idea would be to try to fill all trucks as much as possible, but packing problems are quite new to me and I have very little knowledge about them.

Comment: This can be easily solved using dynamic programming, give it a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Dynamic_programming_in_computer_programming

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I can't really see why it would help me solve this exact problem.

Comment: It seems that the "only taking the first or last item" rule doesn't have any effect, unless it means that you only know the weight of the first and last item, and don't know what's in the middle of the row.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can indeed be solved by dynamic programming; however this might be difficult without previous experiece with the approach. The recurrence relation and state space could be defined as follows.

Let `n` denote the number of items and `i_1,...,i_n` their sizes; let `m` denote the number of trucks and let `c_1,...,c_m` denote their capacity. The state space can be implemented as an `m+2`-dimensional table, where the entry at position `(k_1,k_2,l_1,...,l_m)` is defined as the maximum possible number of items selected from the complement of the items `{k_1,...,k_2}` (which then is the remaining queue of items) where truck `k` has remaining load exactly `l_k` or negative infitity of no such solution exists. After initialization of states corresponding to base cases, the state space can be evaluated iteratively by using the recurrence relation

```
(k_1,k_2,l_1,...,l_m) = max
                        {
                            (k_1+1,k_2,l_1,...,l_m),
                            (k_1,k_2+1,l_1,...,l_m),

                            (k_1+1,k_2,l_1-i_k_1,...,l_m) + 1, m cases in total
                            ...,
                            (k_1+1,k_2,l_1,...,l_m-i_k_1) + 1,

                            (k_1,k_2-1,l_1-i_k_2,...,l_m) + 1, m cases in total
                            ...,
                            (k_1,k_2-1,l_1,...,l_m-i_k_2) + 1,
                        }
```

where the first two cases correspond to discarding the left end and the right end of the queue, the next `m` cases correspond to packing the item at the left end of the queue to each of the `m` trucks and the last `m` cases correspond to packing the item at the right end of the queue to each of the `m` trucks.

After evaluating the state space, one has to examine all end states; these are the ones in which every item has either be packed or discarded. These states are the ones for which `k_1 = k_2-1` holds, i.e. the queue would be empty. The implementation would take the maximum value of these; if the result is negative infinity, no feasible solution exists.

Comment: What does k_1 and k_2 stand for?

Comment: They stand for the indices pointing to the beginning and the end of the queue.